# Adding multiple buildings to a quote

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to find a quick way of adding multiple buildings to a quote. There are just 4 fields required, `QuoteID`, `scope`, `known hazards` and the building `row id`.  The same scope and hazards details are the same for each record.

So say I have the following fields and data:

```
$Scope: "All rooms in the building"
$knownHazards: "None"
$quoteID: 1234
$buildingsToAdd: "1,2,4,7,8,10,26"
```

I can use the `$buildingsToAdd`, turn into an array and loop through and use that to create an `Insert` Query for each element in the array, but I was hoping there was a better, quicker and more elegant way.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the approach you described. You could build a single `insert` statement inserting multiple `values` entries instead, but you wouldn't gain much (you'd still have to create a loop). Up to you.

Comment: If you build a single insert statement, as @El_Vanja describes, it is easier to rollback if there is an error in one of the values to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted:

```
        $sql= "insert into tblQuoteBuildings (quoteRowID, buildingID, scope, otherRequirements  )  select :quoteID as quoteRowID,  buildingID, :scope as scope, :knownHazards as otherRequirements from tblSiteInformation where buildingID in($assetRowIDs)" ;
        $stmt = $dbSBS->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':quoteID', $quoteID, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->bindValue(':scope', $scope, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindValue(':knownHazards', $knownHazards, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;

        $stmt->execute();
```

Thank you for the hints